# Material-table: prop.theme is undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using Material-table in reactjs to display data. However, it compiles with the warning:

```
Uncaught TypeError: props.theme is undefined
renderFooter material-table.js:872
render material-table.js:1019
React 17
js index.js:7
factory react refresh:6
Webpack 3
```

I keep getting blank screen with this error, hence, can't proceed with my project.

Comment: Show your full code

Answer (score 1):

same error. Did a clean install and used [material-table-crud][1] example just now

Fixed it now. Updated everything in the project. Deleted node modules etc.

"material-table": "^1.69.3"

Comment: Thanks! What's the "[material-table-crud]"

Comment: sorry.. was a link:  https://github.com/traptrick/material-table-crud. I am using that example